# python - What produces the same plot as autocorrelation_plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I need the values of the autocorrelation coefficients coming from the `autocorrelation_plot()`. The problem is that the output coming from this function is not accessible, so I need another function to get such values. That's why I used `acf()` from `statsmodels` but it didn't get the same plot as `autocorrelation_plot()` does. Here is my code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.sin(np.arange(1,6*np.pi,0.1))
plt.plot(acf(y))
plt.show()
```

So the result is not the same as this:

```
autocorrelation_plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to the `nlags` parameter of `acf`:

> nlags: int, optional
>       Number of lags to return autocorrelation for.

I don't know what exactly this does but in the [source](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py#L475) of `acf` there is a slicing
that shortens the array:

```
avf = acovf(x, unbiased=unbiased, demean=True, fft=fft, missing=missing)
acf = avf[:nlags + 1] / avf[0]
```

If you use `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acovf` directly the result is the same as with `autocorrelation_plot`:

```
avf = acovf(x, unbiased=unbiased, demean=True, fft=fft, missing=missing)
```

So you can call it like

```
plt.plot(acf(y, nlags=len(y)))
```

to make it work.

An explanation of lag: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548314/what-is-lag-in-a-time-series/2548350